# Line breaks unexpectedly appearing on sprite

Tags: css, text-alignment

I am trying to put some sprites into a footer widget. When I install the sprite with the code I have, I end up with my images being on 4 lines instead of 1. I am not sure where I erred in my code.

The sprite html is

```
<div>
  <a class="calendar-sp" href="http://www.tara.meditationinsantabarbara.org/calendar"></a>
  <a class="twitter-sp" href="http://www.twitter.com/MahakankalaBC/"></a>
  <a class="facebook-sp" href="http://www.facebook.com/MahakankalaBuddhistCenter/"></a>
  <a class="eBooklead-sp" href="http://www.emodernbuddhism.com/"></a>
</div>
```

And my sprite css is

```
a.calendar-sp,
a.eBooklead-sp,
a.twitter-sp,
a.facebook-sp
 {
    display: inline-block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image:url ('http://www.tara.meditationinsantabarbara.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/SocialSpriteSheet5.png');
}

a.calendar-sp
{
        width:  184px;
    height: 175px;
}

a.eBooklead-sp
{
    background-position:    -184px 0;
    width:  213px;
    height: 175px;
}

a.twitter-sp {
    background-position:    -397px 0;
    width:  128px;
    height: 128px;
    }

a.facebook-sp
{
    background-position:    -525px 0;
    width:  128px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Also, my sprite images occasionally disappear!

Comment: Works fine here except for the space between url and ()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5Tnar/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the width of the div to allow all your buttons to apear next to each other, i would also add a float:left or float:right to let the browser know you want the sprites to locate themselves in that fashion